# scalacheck/scalatest not found: how to add it in sbt/scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I've installed typesafe-stack from http://typesafe.com/stack/download on my ubuntu12, than I created a play project (g8 typesafehub/play-scala) and now I want to add scalatest or scalacheck to my project.

So my_app/project/plugins.sbt has the following lines:

```
// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.1")
```

Then I added scalatest using addSbtPlugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M1" % "test")
```

and now it fails with the following message when I run 'sbt test'

```
[info] Resolving org.scalatest#scalatest;2.0.M1 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scalatest#scalatest;2.0.M1
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalatest/scalatest/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.0.M1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   ~/.ivy2/local/org.scalatest/scalatest/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.0.M1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.9.1_0.11.3/2.0.M1/scalatest-2.0.M1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-    releases/org.scalatest/scalatest/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.0.M1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.9.1_0.11.3/2.0.M1/scalatest-2.0.M1.pom
```

What I don't understand: why does it use this http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.9.1_0.11.3/2.0.M1/scalatest-2.0.M1.pom URL instead of the real one http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.9.1/2.0.M1/scalatest_2.9.1-2.0.M1.pom?

Quite the same problem I have with scalacheck: it also tries to download using sbt-version specific artifactId whereas the repository has only scala-version specific.

What am I doing wrong? I understand there must be a switch in sbt somewhere, not to use sbt-version as part of the artifact URL?

I also tried using this in my plugins.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M1" % "test"
```

but looks like it is completely ignored by sbt and scalatest.jar hasn't appeared in the classpath:

```
my_app/test/AppTest.scala:1: object scalatest is not a member of package org
[error] import org.scalatest.FunSuite
```

because the output of sbt clean && sbt test has lots of 
    Resolving org.easytesting#fest-util;1.1.6 or just another library, but nothing about scalatest.

### I use scala 2.9.1 and sbt 0.11.3, trying to use scalatest 2.0.M1 and 1.8; scalacheck:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
  "releases"  at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.9" % "test"
)
```

---

With the same outcome, i.e. it uses the sbtVersion specific POM URL, which doesn't exist.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The same problem with scaliak: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/stackmob/scaliak_2.9.1/0.1.1-SNAPSHOT/ is the real URL, but my SBT tries https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/stackmob/scaliak_2.9.1_0.11.3/0.1.1-SNAPSHOT/scaliak-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.pom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scalatest is not a build plugin, but a testing library. You should add it like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M1" % "test"
```

And you should add it to `build.sbt` at the base directory of your project (which you referred to as "my_app"), *not* to `project/plugins.sbt`.

The reason it has `0.11.3` in the URL it tries to find is because build plugins are tied to the version of SBT you are using.

Answer (score 4):

The `plugins.sbt` file and the `addSbtPlugin` are used to add sbt plugins. Not dependencies.

With the template you used, you should add your dependencies in the `project/Build.scala`. You will find a section with:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  // Add your project dependencies here,
)
```

Replace it with:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.9" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M1" % "test"
)
```

and it should work.